# Bootstrap not indenting inner rows/columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am noticing that bootstrap is not indenting my inner rows and columns.

When I create the top level row/column there is  padding on the left an right sides.  However as I nest that padding is not applied:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    Left Side
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background: #AAAAAA">
    Right Side
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        Right Side Inner 1
        <div class="row" style="background: yellow;">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Right Side Inner 1.1
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Right Side Inner 1.2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        Right Side Inner 2
        <div class="row" style="background: green;">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Right Side Inner 2.1
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            Right Side Inner 2.2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/remf5q4ltkQzM55553tB?p=preview

Notice how the padding on the outer most column-6 (grey) is the same padding as the inner content (yellow and green).

Does bootstrap only pad the first level of row/columns?

Answer (score 0):

Rows do two things:
- clear fix the floating child columns.
- offset the outer most padding of the first and last columns. This offset allows infinite nesting.

By putting the background color on a column then a inner row, you are highlighting this offset. Try adding a bg color to just col-sm-6 to see how the content areas line up.

This will help show you the nesting...

```
.col-sm-6{
  Background: #eee;
}
.col-sm-6 .col-sm-6{
   Background: #ccc;
}
.col-sm-6 .col-sm-6 .col-sm-6{
  Background: #aaa;
}
```

Etc.